# Sumproduct Wildcard issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I have the following formula in cell R5:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((I4:N28)*(B4:B28=R3)*(I1:N1="*"&R4&"*"))
```

I would expect it to return 120 but returns 0.  It transpires I can not use wildcard in sumproduct() like I typically would with sumif().  Any help on incorporating a wildcard into sumproduct() is appreciated.

[image]

Many thanks, Alan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following formula which uses `SEARCH()` Function.

[image]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(R4,I3:N3)))*(B4:B19=R3)*(I4:N19))
```

---

Another alternative way:

[image]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT((1-ISERR(SEARCH(R4&"*",I3:N3)))*(R3=B4:B19)*(I4:N19))
```

---